# How to change the header color in materialize?

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, materialize

I work on a web template but I want to change the color that is shown in Android browser (maybe JS ?). By default, it's a blue one
How can I change it ?

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Dave Plug said, meta is the way to go. In order to have it work on all devices, you can do this:

```
<!-- This is for Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#222">
<!-- This is for Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#222">
<!-- This is for iOS - Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#222">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the color of the browser, to do that you can use the metatag theme-color:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
```

It's definitely supported by chrome on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Materilizecss offers a wide range of Color Palettes to you. You can simple apply that to your nav.

**HTML :**

```
<nav class="red lighten-1" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Note:** You can also write your custom class and apply that to nav.

**Ref :** http://materializecss.com/color.html

**JSFiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/btc8707k/